# How to perform overflow stack position in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i'm new to flutter and wanted to ask how to perform the bottom centre overflow the container in the stack widget. I'm tried but have not been able to get the expected result that I want.

Actual Result:
[image: Actual Result]

Expected Result:
[image]

Comment: hey, please put your code, not screen shot of your code,and let me help you after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Position(
   bottom: 0, // 0 means at the bottom of defined Spaces by its Parent Widget
)
```

if you want to access over that spaces than u can use negative value.

```
Position(
   bottom: -0 to ...... any as u desired
)
```

** but remember one thing usually Stack doesn't allow to show that overflowed area, as it initially defined "clipBehavior: false", so to change this

```
Stack(
  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
  children:[ Position(bottom: -50)]
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it's quite useful for me as a beginner!

Answer (score 1):

here is what you need:

```
class ProfileLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfileLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Stack(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.blue[100],
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: const [
              SizedBox(height: 150,),
               SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  child: Placeholder()),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

as you see, when you want to use `Stack`, imagine that every child in Stack is a separate screen.

please attention to code that you have a Container with height of 200,
and your Placeholder you are showing is separated. and because your placeholder height is 100 you need to have `SizedBox(height: 150,)`.

[image]

happy coding...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it's quite useful for me as a beginner!

Answer (score -1):

Stack(
children: [
Positioned(
left: 20.0,
top: 20.0,
child: Text('Child Widget 1'),
),
Positioned(
right: 20.0,
bottom: 20.0,
child: Text('Child Widget 2'),
),
],
)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Stack(
clipBehavior: Clip.none,
children:[ Position(bottom: -50)]
)

After hours u can just change your position to -50 and clipbehaviour clip.none

overflow. Visible is not working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).